# Integral of $x^2z$ using Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : 0≤z≤1−x^2−y^2\}$ and $f(x,y,z)=x^2z$. Calculate $\int_A f$.

I used Fubini's theorem and polar coordinates to write it as $$\int_A f = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1-r^2} (rcos(\theta))^2 \cdot z \cdot r \quad drd\theta dz$$

which leads me to $$\int_Af=\pi \int_0^\infty r^3 \frac{r^4-2r^2+1}{2}dr$$ where the RHS is $\infty$ but I know that I need to find a finite result and I did the integrals with a calculator so I don't think its a computation error, maybe a theoretical one ?

Comment: Note that $1 - x^2 - y^2 = 1 - (x^2 + y^2)$. As $x^2$ and $y^2$ must be $\ge 0$ for all real values of $x$ and $y$, $1 - (x^2 + y^2)$ cannot have a value $ \gt 1$. So the upper bound is $1$ and not $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0 \leq 1-x^{2}-y^{2}$ forces $r$ to be $ \leq 1$ so the integral w.r.t. $r$ is from $0$ to $1$.